# How to properly connect to MongoDB using Cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to connect to my Atlas cluster only once per instance running Cloud Functions.

Here is my code for an instance :

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const client = new MongoClient("myUrl", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

exports.myHttpMethod = functions.region("europe-west1").runWith({
  memory: "128MB",
  timeoutSeconds: 20,
}).https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("Data is: ", data);
  client.connect(() => {
    const testCollection = client.db("myDB").collection("test");
    testCollection.insertOne(data);
  });
});
```

And i would like to avoid the `client.connect()` in each function call that seems to be really too much.

I would like to do something like this :

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const client = await MongoClient.connect("myUrl", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = client.db("myDB");

exports.myHttpMethod = functions.region("europe-west1").runWith({
  memory: "128MB",
  timeoutSeconds: 20,
}).https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("Data is: ", data);
  const testCollection = db.collection("test");
  testCollection.insertOne(data);
});
```

But i can't `await` like this.
In my AWS Lambda functions (running in python) i have not this issue and i am able to connect only once per instance, so i guess there is an equivalent but i don't know much JS / Node JS.

Comment: What do you mean by "await"?

Comment: if i don't "await", the `client` var will be a `Promise` and useless because `db` will not be initialized either as `client.db` doesn't exist on a `Promise` object, i want it to be initialized outside of the functions

Comment: and the `const db = await lient.db("myDB");` is not accepted because you aren't in a async context, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store your database client as a [global variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations). From the documentation,

> Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation. If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.

Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"; 

let client: MongoClient | null;

const getClient = async () => {
  if (!client) {
    const mClient = new MongoClient("[MONGODB_URI]", {});
    client = await mClient.connect();
    functions.logger.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  } else {
    functions.logger.log("Using existing MongoDB connection");
  }
  functions.logger.log("Returning client");
  return client;
};

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    const db = (await getClient()).db("[DATABASE]");
    const result = await db.collection("[COLLECTION]").findOne({});
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
  }
);
```

This should reuse the connection for that instance.

[image]