# Can we setup Native MongoDB connection in Firebase Cloud Functions with Nodejs and Express.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const getClient = async () => {
 try {
    if (!client) {
      const mClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL, {});
      client = await mClient.connect();
      console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    } else {
      console.log("Using existing MongoDB connection");
    }
    console.log("Returning client");
    return client;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Errrr",error);
  }
};

let dbConnect = (await getClient()).db('TestDB')
```

I am trying but can't get success

```
let dbConnect = (await getClient()).db('TestDB')
```

getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: you should not use await keyword out side of the async function remove await getClient () with getClient();

Comment: thanks but it's also not working still getting same error

Comment: That's from one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619974/13130697) and I'm pretty sure the `getClient()` is called within the async Cloud function. Can you share the complete code that you've tried running and also the complete error so we can check what identifier it is referring to?