# My google cloud functions take longer and longer each call

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, redis, google-cloud-functions

Here's a patebin of the code (password isn't real): https://pastebin.com/Br37dX8r

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const redis = require("redis");
const regionInfo = require("./regionInfo.json");

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
    database: 0,
    password: "hunter123",
    url: "redis://database.skeld.net",
    socket: 6379,
 });

app.get("/games", async (request, response) => {
    console.log("/games request");
    await client.connect();
    const codes = await client.sMembers("skeldsync.games");
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=10, s-maxage=20");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var lobbyInfos = new Array();
    for (const idx in codes) {
        const code = codes[idx];
        const lobbyInfo = await client.hGetAll("ImpostorRedis" + code);
        if (lobbyInfo.in_progress == "true") continue;
        lobbyInfos.push(lobbyInfo.lobby_data);
    }
    var result = `${JSON.stringify(lobbyInfos)}`;
    response.send(result);
    console.log("Lobby infos length: " + lobbyInfos.length);
    await client.disconnect();
});
 
app.get("/playercount", async (request, response) => {
    console.log("/playercount request");
    await client.connect();
    const codes = await client.sMembers("skeldsync.games");
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=5, s-maxage=10");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var totalPlayers = 0;
    for (const idx in codes) {
        const code = codes[idx];
        const str = await client.hGet("ImpostorRedis" + code, "player_count");
        if (str == null) continue;
        const playerCount = Number.parseInt(str);
        totalPlayers += playerCount;
    }
    var result = `${totalPlayers}`;
    response.send(result);
    console.log("Total players: " + result);
    await client.disconnect();
});
 
app.get("/regionInfo", async (request, response) => {
    console.log("/regionInfo request");
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=3600");
    response.send(regionInfo);
});
 
app.get("/ip", async (request, response) => {
    console.log("/ip request");
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=3600");
    response.send(regionInfo.Regions[0].Servers[0].Ip);
});
 
app.get("/deeplink", async (request, response) => {
    console.log("/deeplink request");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=3600");
    response.send(
        `amongus://init\?servername=<color=\"orange\">skeld.net\&serverport=22023\&serverip=${regionInfo.Regions[0].Servers[0].Ip}\&usedtls=false`
    );
});
 
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I know it's not the cleanest code. That is okay, it's a simple and small API.
Issue is, that each time an API request is made it takes longer and longer. Starting at 100ms but after a few thousand calls by my users it takes upwards of 12000ms per call.

I'm really not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Can you try reusing the connection instead of closing the connection every time similar [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619974/13130697)?

Comment: You may check for [Tips and Tricks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#min) and 
[dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#use_dependencies_wisely)
You can also try to understand and look for if any specific function is facing delay while executing and or are there any errors or warning messages.

Check links
[AsynchronousRequest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_asynchronous_request)   and [Cloudfucntions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-async)

Comment: Daniel, did the document help with your issues.