# Code outside of cloud function is executed, occasionally

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a textbook Google Cloud Function as follows:

```
const fs = require("fs");

console.log("Here!");

exports.validateTemperature = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("There");
  // ...
};
```

It is triggered by Cloud Scheduler once every 15 minutes.

I expect the line `Here!` to be printed when the function is deployed. However, occasionally when the function is invoked, `Here!` is also printed, and sometimes it occurs *after* `There` is printed.

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything outside of the function scope falls in [Global scope](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-scopes#functions_tips_scopes-nodejs). That runs every time a new instance for the Cloud Function starts (popularly known as the cold start). It is mostly used to execute any time consuming tasks so they are executed only once per instance and not every function invocation. The value is shared across all invocations handled by that instance.

A simple example would reusing database connection instead of creating a new one every time as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353766/how-to-properly-connect-to-mongodb-using-cloud-functions).

Comment: So it's possible there are more than one instances of the function running at the same time?

Comment: @OldGeezer yes , especially in Gen 1 functions. Cloud functions gen 2 can handle upto 3000 requests concurrently so it's less frequent.

Comment: My log shows that the global scope is executed at the top of every hour before my function is invoked, and at every 30 minutes past the hour *after* the function has been invoked. Is there a possibility that an instance is killed if it is unused after a while, and then re-spun up upon invocation?

Comment: @OldGeezer I am not sure if there's a fixed duration on how long an instance will run but yes its roughly around 30 minutes so that must have been a new instance.